# Make a painted model glow

Tags: materials

How would I make a painted model glow? All the tutorials I've found only let basic materials glow , like making a blank cube glow, etc. Currently, I make my model glow by changing its material to Emission shader and Transparent BSDF, but in that way, my model is either completely dark, or glowing, but I can't find a way to keep the paint (ie the character's face)...

Comment: Can you show a bit of your scene with the issue?

Comment: Have you tried using the color map in the emission color slot?

Answer (score 2):

Create a black and white mask for the areas you want to make glow. Then combine emission material with any material you want, using Mix Shader Node and apply your mask into Mix Shader factor (see on screen) Hope it is what you were looking for...
[image]

[image]